# Output from a method not displaying properly

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created 4 classes and one class to test everything. I think I have all the code correctly put in for 3 of the classes.

In my `testVehicle`, I have to make two objects with declared type Vehicle but actual type `PassCar`. Make at least one object of declared type Vehicle but actual type Truck. Make an array of type Vehicle with the instances created above. Execute a void method named show with the Vehicle array as its sole argument.

Create a Vehicle `ArrayList` from the array already created. In the show method use a foreach loop to process the Object array. For each Object, display its description method followed by the `toString` method. Create the four classes as above.

Do NOT add any attributes or methods that don't appear in the UML diagrams. The `description()` method outputs a string describing the class. See the first line about each vehicle below. Override description in each subclass. Don't modify anything. Create an executable class named `VehicleTest` to test your work. In `VehicleTest`, add code that accomplishes the tasks below. The sample output might assist you to understand these tasks.

It has been a while since I have used to Java so I am very rusty. I have read books, looked for information on line but I sill can't get my code to display the proper way.

This is what it is supposed to look like:

Output from the show method.

In this application, a passenger car is an every day vehicle registered to an individual:

```
make=Ford, model=Mustang, year=2016, price=44500.0
PassCar numPass=5, AC=true
Motor EcoBoost, cylinders=6, bhp=310, displacement=2.3

In this application, a Truck is a vehicle designed to transport cargo

make=Dodge, model=Ram, year=2016, price=46000.0
Truck type=pickup, capacity=1500
Motor Hemi, cylinders=8, bhp=707, displacement=5.7

In this application, a passenger car is an every day vehicle registered to an individual

make=Tesla, model=Model S, year=2016, price=121000.0
PassCar numPass=2, AC=true
Motor P90D, cylinders=0, bhp=762, displacement=0.0

Output from ArrayList in main

make=Ford, model=Mustang, year=2016, price=44500.0
PassCar numPass=5, AC=true
Motor EcoBoost, cylinders=6, bhp=310, displacement=2.3

make=Dodge, model=Ram, year=2016, price=46000.0
Truck type=pickup, capacity=1500
Motor Hemi, cylinders=8, bhp=707, displacement=5.7

make=Tesla, model=Model S, year=2016, price=121000.0
PassCar numPass=2, AC=true
Motor P90D, cylinders=0, bhp=762, displacement=0.







 import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;


        public class TestVehicle {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Motor motor1 = new Motor("EcoBoost", 6, 310, 2.3);
            Motor motor2 = new Motor("P90D",0,762,0.0);
            Motor motor3=  new Motor("Hemi", 8, 707, 5.7);

            Vehicle vehicle1=new PassCar("Ford","Mustang",2016
            ,44500.0,5,true,motor1); 

            Vehicle vehicle2=new PassCar("Tesla","Model 
            S",2016,121000.0,2,true,motor2);

            Vehicle vehicle3=new Truck("Dodge","Ram",2016,46000.0, 
              "pickup",1500,motor3);

            Vehicle[] ara = { vehicle1,vehicle2, vehicle3 };
            showVehicle(ara);

    ArrayList<Vehicle> ara2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ara));
            for (int i = 0; i < ara2.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(ara2.get(i));
            }

           }

        public static void showVehicle(Vehicle[]ara) {
            for(Object i: ara){
                 System.out.println(i);



    }
        }
        }

Vehicle Class

    public class Vehicle {
        String make;
        String model;
        int year;
        double price;

        public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price) {
            super();
            this.make = make;
            this.model = model;
            this.year = year;
            this.price = price;

    }   
        public void description() {
            System.out.println("In this application, a passenger car is an every day vehicle registered to an individual." );
            }

        public String toString() {
            return "Vehicle make="  + this.make + ", model=" + this.model + ", year=" + this.year + ", price=" + this.price + " " ;


        }

        }

PassCar

    public class PassCar extends Vehicle {
        int numPass;
        boolean AC;
        Motor motor;

        public PassCar(String make, String model, int year, double price, int numPass, boolean AC, Motor motor) {
            super(make, model, year, price);
            this.numPass = numPass;
            this.AC = AC;
            this.motor = motor;

    }
        @Override
        public void description() {
            System.out.println("This application, a passanger car is an every day vehicle registered to an individual");

        }


        public String toString() {
        return "numPass=" + this.numPass + "AC=" + this.AC+ "Motor=" + this.motor;
        }

        }


Truck Class

    public class Truck extends Vehicle {
        String type;
        int capacity;
        Motor motor;

        public Truck(String make, String model, int year, double price, String type, int capacity, Motor motor) {
        super(make, model, year, price);
        this.type = type;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.motor = motor;

    }
        @Override
        public void description() {
            System.out.println("In this application, a Truck is a vehicle designed to transport cargo");
        }


        public String toString() {
        return "Type="+ this.type+"Capacity="+ this.capacity+ "Motor=" + this.motor;

    }
    }

Motor Class

    public class Motor {
        String name;
        int cylinders;
        int bhp;
        double displacement;

        public Motor(String name, int cylinders, int bhp, double displacement) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cylinders = cylinders;
        this.bhp = bhp;
        this.displacement = displacement;

    }

        public String toString() {
        return "Motor name=" + this.name + ", cylinders=" + this.cylinders + ", bhp" + this.bhp + ", displacement" + this.displacement;

        }

        }
```

Comment: Simply posting your assignment here and your code is not likely going to get you the help you need. Instead, please clarify the exact problem you're having and post a [mcve] that demonstrates it.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve]; providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the output you want you need to call the vehicles toString() method once for each object. But this cannot be done since you have overriden the Vehicle Classes methods in the Child classes. So you will have to define another method in the vehicle class and call that instead

```
class Vehicle {
        public String toString2() {
            return "Vehicle make="  + this.make + ", model=" + this.model + ", year=" + this.year + ", price=" + this.price + " " ;
        }
}
```

You can print it using

```
public static void showVehicle(Vehicle[]ara) {
            for(Vehicle i: ara){
                 i.description();
                 System.out.println(i.toString2());
                 System.out.println(i);

            }
}
```

Since you define the motor property for the two types of vehicles at the subclass level you cannot print the motors using a Vehicle Object So you should check what type of Object they are using the instanceof Method and downcast

```
if (i instanceof PassCar){
     System.out.println(((PassCar)i).motor);
}
```